# Schmidt decomposition of entangled state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, linear-algebra

I have a problem with some homework our teacher assigned. I have to find the Schmidt decomposition of the entangled state 
$$\lvert\psi\rangle_{A,B}=\frac{1}{2}\lvert0\rangle_{A}\lvert0\rangle_{B}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}\lvert1\rangle_{A}\lvert0\rangle_{B}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}\lvert0\rangle_{A}\lvert1\rangle_{B}.$$
Looking in my notebook, I can't find anything useful. I was hoping I could get a lead on how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

First, the coefficient matrix of the state is:
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}& -\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}\\
-\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}& 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
The state could be rewritten as:
$$\lvert\psi\rangle_{A,B} = \sum_{ij}a_{ij}\lvert i\rangle_A\lvert j\rangle_B  =\sum_{ijk}u_{ik}d_{kk}v_{kj}\lvert i\rangle_A\lvert j\rangle_B= \sum_{k}d_{kk}\lvert k\rangle_A\lvert k\rangle_B$$ 
where $A = UDV$ is the singular-value decomposition of A, $\lvert k\rangle_A = \sum_{i}u_{ik}\lvert i\rangle_A$, $\lvert k\rangle_B = \sum_{j}v_{kj}\lvert j\rangle_B$. The final decomposition in this formula is the Schmidt decomposition.

Therefore, to find the Schmidt decomposition, you need to find the singular-value decomposition of A: $A = UDV$, where U and V are orthogonal matrices (if A is complex, then hermitian matrices), and D is a **non-negative diagonal** matrix.

To find U, V and D, you use 2 properties:
$$A^TA = V^TD^2V$$
$$AA^T = U^TD^2U$$
In other words, you should do eigenvalue problems of $A^TA$ and $AA^T$.